# When i change a setting of my SharePoint list template does the change apply to all the lists i have created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-template

When I change a setting of my SharePoint list template does the change apply to all the lists I have created from that template?

Comment: How you created list template & how you are changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

If you are making changes in list template after creating SharePoint lists, new changes will not be applied to lists created before the changes.

These will only be applied to new lists you will create after changes.